# Нужна запятая перед тире?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Я наловил достаточно рыбы. Если я засушу её, то хватит на несколько дней, - это избавит меня от ежедневной рыбалки.

Answer (score 2):

**Если я засушу её, то хватит на несколько дней, ― это избавит меня от ежедневной рыбалки.**

Запятая и тире как единый знак может использоваться в бессоюзном сложном предложении, в том числе перед ЭТО. Однако в современных текстах этот знак утрачивает свою актуальность, поэтому в подобных конструкциях запятая может отсутствовать. **Запятая действительно кажется лишней**, так как ничего не добавляет к пониманию структуры предложения.

ПАС: http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=135#pp135

Примечание 1. В бессоюзном сложном предложении может ставиться запятая и тире как единый знак, особенно при значении присоединения во второй части предложения (знак этот в настоящее время утрачивает свою активность): **Смотреть наружу не было смысла, — тьма ночи налетала всё более густыми волнами** (Пауст.);

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp151

Примечание. Часто при наличии перед присоединительным предложением слова ЭТО между частями бессоюзного сложного предложения ставятся запятая и тире: **Русская интеллигенция росла и развивалась в условиях совершенно зверских, — это неоспоримо** (М. Г.).